# How to test an attribute when using KiWi in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tdd, kiwi

I'm learning how to following TDD using KiWi Framework, my first problem so far is about how can I ask for an existing atributte into a UIViewController class, something like this:

```
it(@"should have ",^{

       UILabel *descriptionLabel = (UILabel *)[viewController objectForPropertyName:@"descriptionLabel"];
       [descriptionLabel shouldNotBeNil];

    });
```

The problem here it's that "objectForPropertyName" is a method of another framework class.

Is there a way to ask for "descriptionLabel" using just Kiwi framework?

Comment: Is `descriptionLabel` just a @property on one of your view controller classes? How is the `viewController` variable declared?